# Adding TAB key java swing keybindings --- What is the correct name?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

```
Action tab = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
            System.err.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        }
    };

Game.panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("Tab"), "tab");
Game.panel.getActionMap().put("tab", tab);
```

However its not printing. This is the same set up that I use for all my other keys, but I can't get the tab key to work. I've tried `"TAB"`, `"Tab"`, and `"tab"`.

What's the correct name for it? Or is there something special?

Comment: Personally prefer `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0)` myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('\t');
```

[`\t` is the escape sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) for the [TAB character (0x09)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart), which is output by pressing [<kbd>tab</kbd> on your keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key).

There is also [`KeyEvent.VK_TAB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_TAB) which might be preferable depending on your use case. See the documentation in `KeyEvent` for more on why you should prefer one or the other.

Comment: how would you incorporate a released '\t' ?

Comment: @MitchWeaver it should be no different than any other key - register a `KeyListener` that overrides [`.keyReleased()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyReleased-java.awt.event.KeyEvent-). In general it's better to post new questions rather than ask follow-ups in comments.

Comment: my bad, I was thinking the opposite that it would be rude to post another. Anyhow, is there a way to stick with the `keybindings` approach than a `KeyListener`? key listeners are slower and can act funky, not the best for games.

Comment: @MitchWeaver I'd definitely suggest you ask that (with more detail) in a separate question, I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: I was just experimenting with that. And yes, it is much easier to use and does solve my released probelm: `getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that KeyStroke works for you since the Tab character is generally handled by the focus subsystem.

It doesn't work for me. I'm using JDK8 on Windows 7:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TabSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public TabSSCCE()
    {
        Action tab = new AbstractAction()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("key typed");
            }
        };

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('1'), "typed");
        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('a'), "typed");
        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('\t'), "typed");
        getActionMap().put("typed", tab);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TabSSCCE());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Does the above code work for you?

Only the "1" and "a" work for me. The Tab key does not work for me.

If not, then can you post a simple SSCCE showing how you are using this?

Edit:

The above code will work with either of the following:

```
frame.setVisible( true );
frame.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
```

or you can disable the focus traversal keys for the panel:

```
public TabSSCCE()
{
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

    ...
}
```

Comment: yea it does, this is how I do all my keys, exactly like how it is in my question. I'm on linux, 8, but my game also works fine on win / mac. Not sure what you're problem is honestly.

Comment: @MitchWeaver, I should clarify, the "1" and "a" work for me, but the "\t" does not. I guess I'm suggesting that you shouldn't be trying to handle the Tab key since the focus traversal system intercepts this key. The code does not work on Windows so you don't have a platform independent solution.

Comment: ahhh I see, yes I haven't tested the tab as I've only just now implemented it. Does `getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)` work for you instead of `"\t"` perhaps?

Comment: @MitchWeaver, no that approach doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Found the solution, I think! Put this where you declare your component: `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);`

Comment: @MitchWeaver, That helped. I got it to work on Windows. See edit.